# Convert all values in a CHAR string column to a DATETIME?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two tables on a date value, however the data type for `table1` is DATETIME and the data type for `table2` is CHAR.

```
table1.[Birthdate] = table2.[Birthdate]
```

I've tried to the following conversions: 
    CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(Birthdate,4)+LEFT(Birthdatee,2)+SUBSTRING(Birthdate,3,2))

but received a *"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."*

I get the same error when trying to store the `table2 Birthdate` as a new column in `table2` formatted as DATETIME.

I've also tried:

```
CONVERT(datetime,Birthdate,23)
```

which returns *"The multi-part identifier "Birthdate" could not be bound."*

- Table1 Birthdate value example: 1962-09-08 00:00:00.000 (**datetime**
  data type)
- Table2 Birthdate value example: 1964-12-11 (**char** data    type)

Comment: Why you're storing dates as strings? You should fix that. Just try `CONVERT(datetime,table2.Birthdate,23)`

Comment: @Sami -  "The multi-part identifier "Birthdate" could not be bound." is the response message I get when running this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sami mentioned as a comment to your question, You shouldn't be storing dates as strings (varchar, nvarchar, or char) in the first place.  Period.   With that being said, you should be able to join by converting to DateTime on Table2.

It should look like the following:

```
CONVERT(DateTime, BirthDate)
```

Your query should look something like the following:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Table1 a 
 LEFT JOIN Table2 b
 ON a.BirthDate = CONVERT(DateTime, b.BirthDate)
```

Check out basic SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/50e02/2):

Comment: I did try this as mentioned in the question but received "The multi-part identifier "Birthdate" could not be bound." I agree it should not be stored as a string, but I have no direct control over the data getting into the table currently.

Comment: What does your query look like then?   This should work, unless you're not labeling/referencing your aliases right, or you're not referencing your tables right on the joins.   This works as is, as referenced in the SQL fiddle.

Comment: "TRYCONVERT" instead of regular "CONVERT" did the trick. Not sure why...